# How to get local restaurants and more precise nearby data using Google Places API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places

I want to develop an application for searching Near by places(restaurants, ATMs etc), Currently I am using Google Places API and it is working fine but the problem is it is not giving me the names of local restaurants present near to me or also giving some restaurants name which are far away from my current location.

All my local restaurants are present and shown on Google Maps in restaurant Category but not providing the same in nearby searches.

When I tries the same using application **NearMe** on play Store its is showing the proper data including all my nearby local restaurants and more precise results.

Is something needs to be done at coding level to get all these local restaurants data and more precise results or **NearMe** using some different API ?

Comment: Are you using `&radius=xxx` in your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this same issue when working with the Google Places API. I was trying to grab the closest places within a specific radius and Google Places would return a random assortment of places within that radius as opposed to the closest 5 or so places.

I did find a very rough work around that might work in your case. I noticed that by tightening up the search radius or distance I received closer places in my query (obviously). But this was the only way I could get the closest places that I knew existed within the API that were close to the current location.

Check out this post that is the same issue.

[Google Places Api sort by distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726446/google-places-api-sort-by-distance)

Comment: Thanks I have already solved the problem with the same concept but thanks its might help others.