# Google Places API returning zero-results with specified keyword

Tags: android, google-api, google-places-api

I am currently doing an Android app that returns the closest places to a user's location that fits his specified preferences (pizza, coffee, bar, etc). In order to do that, I am using [Nearby Search Requests](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search) in the Google Places API. This is how I build my HTTP request:

```
public String createRequestURL() {
    String requestURL = "";

    if ((googleApiKey != "") && (lat <= MAX_GOOGLE_LAT) && (lat >=  MIN_GOOGLE_LAT)
            && (lng <= MAX_GOOGLE_LNG) && (lng >= MIN_GOOGLE_LNG)) {
        requestURL += "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?";
        requestURL += "location=" + lat + "," + lng;
        requestURL += "&rankby=distance";
        requestURL += "&keyword=" + keyword;
        requestURL += "&opennow";
        requestURL += "&key=" + googleApiKey;
    }

    return requestURL;
}
```

The test query I am trying to execute is with lat = 45.5017, lng = 73.5673, keyword = "pizza", which is to find all pizza places that are open now near Montreal.

When I execute that query to the API, I get the `ZERO_RESULTS` status back all the time. I was using the `radius` field before, but have since read this [question and answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726446/google-places-api-sort-by-distance) and it seems that using `rankby` in the query and then removing all query responses which are further than X meters in my app is better for what I want my app to do.

Why am I getting the `ZERO_RESULTS` status back instead of actual pizza, coffee, bar, etc places nearby my location?

---

EDIT:

I have tried the following request as well:

```
public String createRequestURL() {
    String requestURL = "";

    if ((googleApiKey != "") && (lat <= MAX_GOOGLE_LAT) && (lat >=  MIN_GOOGLE_LAT)
            && (lng <= MAX_GOOGLE_LNG) && (lng >= MIN_GOOGLE_LNG)) {
        requestURL += "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?";
        requestURL += "location=" + lat + "," + lng;
        requestURL += "&rankby=distance";
        requestURL += "&types=food";
        requestURL += "&key=" + googleApiKey;
    }

    return requestURL;
}
```

And this simple request is still returning the status `ZERO_RESULTS`.

Comment: Have you tried removing parameters such as `opennow` and `keyword` and giving a location where you know for sure there is something going on nearby? I think that could be a good first step to be sure that everything is fine with the most basic query.

Comment: @AlvaroSantisteban I have tried removing `opennow`, and I get the same `ZERO_RESULTS` status back from the API. I unfortunately cannot remove `keyword` as it is required (that, or `types` or `name`) when the `rankby=` field is used.

Comment: If you are not mistyping. you might want to say lng = -73.5673 for Montreal

Comment: Oh god, thanks, that was indeed the problem. You can put it as an answer, I'll chose it as official answer.

Comment: Also it's good to know that if you're visiting the shores of Lake Balkhash, there are no pizza places around, so you might want to bring along your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change lng = -73.5673 for Montreal.