# what type of Google map api use to search specific place like hospital in a redious

Tags: android, api, google-maps

hii everyone I am new in android and I don't have any idea about Google map api for android my question is that in my Android App I want to implement Google map which can search only hospital in a specific radius from users current location so now please tell me what kind of api I need to use to achieve this thank you

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: yes i have tried google map place Api

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [Google Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search). It allows you to query for place information on a variety of categories, such as: establishments, prominent points of interest, geographic locations, and more.

Here is an example of a search request for places of type 'food' within a 500m radius of a point in Sydney, Australia, containing the word 'cruise' in their name:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

> Note that you'll need to replace the key in this example with your own key in order for the request to work in your application.

Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726446/google-places-api-sort-by-distance) on how to return the closest 20 location to the users current location.