# How to combine Places nearby api and Places details api? retrofit java rx

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java

I m very new to android and i need some help, please.
I need to get restaurants nearby the user, and display their informations in a recycler view.
So i use Places api: nearby and details.
I have two requests, one that fetch one list of restaurants nearby the user (i retrieve one object that contains a list of restaurants objects, i save them in an array of restaurants objects)
And one that fetch the details of each restaurant found by the first request (it needs the place s id to work, found with the first request).
The problem is that the requests are not executed in the good order, so my recycler view doesn't display in the good way.
I should probably chain my requests to have only one? 
I made some research but i can't find how to do that, because i need to make the second request for each restaurants found in the first request.

Here are my streams

How should i make one streams with them?

```
private static PlacesService placesService = PlacesService.retrofit.create(PlacesService.class);


    public static Observable<RestaurantObject> streamFetchRestaurants(String latitudeLongitude, int radius, String type, String apiKey) {
        return placesService.getRestaurants(latitudeLongitude,radius,type, apiKey)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public static Observable<RestaurantInformationObject> streamFetchRestaurantInfos(String id, String apikey) {
        return placesService.getRestaurantInfo(id, apikey)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Places Api sort by distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726446/google-places-api-sort-by-distance)

Answer (score 0):

Using `concatMap` should archive what you want:

```
streamFetchRestaurants(latLon, radius, type, apiKey)
            .concatMap(restaurantObject -> streamFetchRestaurantInfos(restaurantObject.id, apiKey))
            .subscribe(restaurantInformationObject -> {
                // Do something with the restaurant information object
            });
```

in contrast to `flatMap` it preserves the original order of your restaurant items. Have a look at the documentation of RxJava or the following article for more details: https://fernandocejas.com/2015/01/11/rxjava-observable-tranformation-concatmap-vs-flatmap/