# Places Search results to sort based on distance in AutoCompleteSupportFragment

Tags: android, sorting, google-places-api, distance, google-places-autocomplete

I am checking for similar results as stated in this link ,it for server side
[Google Places Api sort by distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726446/google-places-api-sort-by-distance)

I need to sort the places based on my nearest distance of mobile android .
But , I dont see any **rankby distance**  in api .

Is there any other way to do in Android for AutoComplete Fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially, their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete) doesn't support rank by distance feature for Autocomplete. This holds true not only for Places Autocomplete for Android, but to [Javascript](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) (client-side) and [web service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) (server-side) as well.

However, a possible workaround would be (depending on your use case), but would be much more expensive, is to  make use of [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix) and create your own Autocomplete depending on its result. So the idea is to:

1. Use place autocomplete where the default behavior is that for every character, 5 suggested places are given.
2. Get each of those 5 address's place ID, and do a Distance Matrix request to all of them to get their distance to one another.
3. Do an event on the textbox and provide those addresses in a dropdown that is sorted by distance. Something like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp)

You might also want to consider filing a feature request for that functionality to be added on their [public issue tracker](http://issuetracker.google.com). Here is a link to guide you for your reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/support